# Xamarin Signature Pad. Cannot save Signature

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, signaturepad

I'm new to Xamarin. I want to implent a signature pad when the user clicks a button and save the signature to a variable. I want to use this signature pad https://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad and I tried to implement the pad as described.

I dont get any errors, but my problem is, that the signature pad appears and I can do the signature and then i can't save the signature, because there's no button. If I click the "back" button of the android phone, the activity which called the signature pad is closed.

[Picture on Android phone: no save button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CHkg.png)

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;
using Environment = Android.OS.Environment;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Provider;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Java.IO;
using SignaturePad;

namespace iSTA
{

[Activity(Label = "Zähler Einbau")]

public class ZEinbau : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ZEinbau);
                    Android.Graphics.Bitmap unterschrift;

        //some other code

        //Button Unterschrift
        Android.Widget.Button btnUnterschrift = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.btnUnterschrift);
        btnUnterschrift.Click += delegate
        {
            SignaturePadView sp = new SignaturePadView(this);
            AddContentView(sp, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));
            unterschrift = sp.GetImage(); ;
        };

        //some other code

    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and remove irrelevant things like namespaces. Also tag either android or forms.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Xamarin.Forms you can use the example I have provided on this Github repository:

https://github.com/15mgm15/Xamarin-Forms-Signature

This example shows you how to save a signature pad without using any component.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It does not come with a SAVE or OK button. It only has the signature pad. 
You can add your own buttons - save, ok, cancel, etc.

For saving, you can save the signature as image or points array.

as image :

```
var image = signature.GetImage();
```

as points array :

```
// Discontinuous lines are separated by PointF.Empty
PointF[] points = signature.Points;
```

Useful links :

- Getting started - https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/signature-pad
- Source - https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad
- Sample Xamarin forms app - https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad/tree/master/samples/Sample.Forms
- Sample android App - https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad/tree/master/samples/Sample.Android